# Most occurring combinations from pack of cards deck

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have history of records for Deck of cards (52) for combinations, now I want to find what are the most occurring combinations from history records.

I can iterate on each card / number and check for combination from history but this is not the efficient algorithm, so I am looking the most used way of finding combinations from history.

Let say I have history in a table:

AKJ

JKQ

AKK

AJJ

A123

AKJ

AkQ

A234

AKQ

AKQ

AKQ

similar to all cards

Now I want to get most occurred combination for A - in the above AKQ -4 tunes

Similarly for all cards

I have tried with foreach card iterate on history and get combinations into list and get count but this is inefficient

I want to know what is the best pattern matching one, do I need to use sets and how?

Comment: Are you just talking about pair-wise combinations? Your question is very abstract at the moment - we have no idea what that history looks like, etc. That makes it hard to answer.

Comment: Edited my question for clarity

Comment: So are there always three cards in each combination, so you're just looking for combinations of two cards plus the specified one? Is ordering important? Do you just have strings, or do you have enums etc for the cards? (If you could give sample code, that would make it easier to provide code in an answer...)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand, you are trying to get the count of the combination which is most frequent for a particular card/number.
And a combination would match a number if the number is present anywhere in the combination.

I think to answer this type of question efficiently for a growing history, you can use a graph to model the history.
The graph would be bipartite (nodes of 2 types). One type of nodes would be each single number (13 of them) and the other type of nodes would be the unique combinations present in the history.

Each combination node would be connected to all the numbers present in the combination. Each combination node would also have a count of its frequency.

In your example, node A would be connected to AKJ(2 times), AKK(1 time), AJJ(1 time), A123(1 time), A234(1 time) and AKQ(4 times).

Whenever a combination occurs, you can check whether it is already present in the graph (using a hash table). If present, increment its count. Else, add a new combination node for it and connect it to the numbers present in it.

Using this graph, you can query the combinations matching any number by iterating through its neighbors and find the neighbor(combination) with the highest frequency. So for A, from the list of its neighbors, the most frequent one is AKQ.

Answer (score 0):

If i suggest your question right, you want to get the count of usages of each card in your history.
What you can do is:

- iterate through the possible cards and find all in history 
  or
- iterate through the history and count the maximum for each card.

To win performance here, it is possible to have a look at the actual maximum count and look how many cards are still in the history.
If you just want to know the kind of card you are finished.
If you want to know the count you have to iterate through all of the cards.